# SQLite: Passing ' in query String

Tags: database, sqlite

I want to add a String data to my table of SQLite database which contains "...O'Clock..." in it. At the time of execution I am getting an syntax error near "Clock" due to the ' in my query string. How to pass ' into that query string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of manipulating each input-string, consider using a 'prepared statement', in which you 'prepare' the sql-query containing a placeholder like '?' for the quote-string. You pass the unmodfied string as it is in the subsequent call (binding the text and execute the query). A good example can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61794729/how-does-prepared-statements-in-sqlite-c-work/61796041#61796041

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass two ' for a single insertion of ' into your table.

Which means your string should be "...O''Clock..."

This should work.