# Regex statment for SQLi prevention

Tags: c++

I need help modifying the function below.

I'm trying to prevent SQL injection in C++. the program should fail and give an error message. I figured out the best approach is to use regular expressions and regex to solve it but not sure how to implement it into the code.

*****I'm supposed to flag "=" and possibly use regex_search() to search for " or = ".*****

```
bool run_query(sqlite3* db, const std::string& sql, std::vector< user_record >& records)
{

// clear any prior results
records.clear();

char* error_message;
if(sqlite3_exec(db, sql.c_str(), callback, &records, &error_message) != SQLITE_OK)
{
std::cout << "Data failed to be queried from USERS table. ERROR = " << error_message << std::endl;
sqlite3_free(error_message);
return false;
}

return true;
}
```

Comment: The best approach is to use prepared statements and let the database handle sqli prevention

Comment: do you have any resources on how to go about that in c++ because I can't find anything, since what I was doing was just flagging and showing an error for the "=" and "  or   =  "I figured that regular expressions would be the easiest most efficient route.

Comment: I really only need these inputs to be flagged: (" or 2=2;"), (" or 'hi'='hi';"), (" or 'hack'='hack';"), (" or 1=1;")

Comment: If you *assume* that's the only things you're protecting against you're making a huge mistake. That's the naive expectation. The truth is often far more complicated, and attackers (and their tools!) usually know better than you.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61794729/how-does-prepared-statements-in-sqlite-c-work) for examples with placeholders. This is really the *only* way to be sure you're safe. If you never inject values, you never have injection bugs.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a real program, you'll never get SQL injection protection done correctly. You absolutely need to use placeholder logic. Hackers are very, very clever.

A Google for `sqlite prepared statement c++` will give you tons of examples to follow. This answer is just one:

[How does prepared statements in Sqlite C++ work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61794729/how-does-prepared-statements-in-sqlite-c-work)